# How to invisible a Linier layout from other activity without using Intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, visibility

I have given here details about my project and I want that when I will click on the Button it will go to the second activity and also it disappears from the second activity layout.

Button btnClick;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnClick = findViewById(R.id.btnClick);

    btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
            startActivity(intent);


            MainActivity2.llOne.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });
```

}
}

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

```
public static LinearLayout llOne;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    llOne = findViewById(R.id.llOne);



}
```

}

Comment: It isn't clear what you want to do. Are you talking about an `Activity` from another app, or an `Activity` from your own app? Can you provide more details? Just edit your question and add the relevant information, then we can help you better!

Comment: suppose, I have taken a LinearLayout and its id is llGroceryVegetable and its java file name is MainActivity.java also I have taken a Second activity which LinearLayout id is llFreshVegetable. Now I want that when I will click on the second activity id llFreshVegetable then the MainActivity Layout id will be visible. So, what will be the functionality of this project?? pls help me... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `SecondActivity` covering `MainActivity`? Does `MainActivity` launch `SecondActivity` and then, when the user clicks on something in `SecondActivity` it returns to `MainActivity`? Is that your architecture?

Comment: not only returns to MainActivity but also a specific Linear Layout will be gone which ID I have mentioned in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments (if I have understood correctly), `MainActivity` should launch `SecondActivity` using `startActivityForResult()`. `SecondActivity` will do whatever and when it is time to return to `MainActivity`, `SecondActivity` should return an `Intent` with some "extras" that `MainActivity` can use to determine what `View` or `Layout` to show/hide. To return the result, `SecondActivity` should call `setResult()`.

In `MainActivity`, implement `onActivityResult()`. This method will be called when `SecondActivity` finishes, and it will be called with the `Intent` that `SecondActivity` passed to `setResult()`. In `onActivityResult()` you can check the returned `Intent` for the "extras" and based on that information you can decide which `View` or `Layout` to hide/show.

Note: If you don't need to use an `Intent` to pass the result back to `MainActivity`, you can just use the `resultCode`, which is in `int`.